# Windows Phone 8 page lifecycle

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I started developing an App for Windows Phone 8 and was wondering how my handling and keeping track of Page-Instances could affect performance and memory consumption.

What is the usual lifecycle of a Page-Object? Can i monitor the necessity of a Page-Object staying alive?

Thanks

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff817008(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Hi, this describes mostly the lifecycle of an app. I'm looking for more info on the lifecycle of a single page inside an app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not so sure if what you ask is the following:

Each Windows Phone Page has a constructor method which is called only once when the page is created - meaning that this method is called only once.

Then comes the `OnNavigatedTo()` and `OnNavigatedFrom()` methods. The first one is the next in line after the constructor when you are navigating from another page to the current one. The navigated from is being called while you are navigating away from the current page - when this page will be added to the page stack (a.k.a. journal).

Next follows the `Loaded()` method which is called after the `OnNavigatedTo()` method and also gets called every time you navigate to the current page.

Finally you have the `OnBackKeyPress()` and `RemovedFromJournal()` methods that gets called when you are trying to navigate away from the page and when the page is 'destroyed'. The first method that gets called here is `OnBackKeyPress()` and then the `RemovedFromJournal()`.

Comment: So, can I be sure, that the instance is never again used after the RemovedFromJournal method? Could that be the point where I could do some cleanup and get rid of any remaining references to the instance?

Comment: as far as I know the removed from journal is the best option. However consider using async methods to do the cleanup (meaning a background thread) since that might delay app's responsiveness.