# Windows phone page not reloading

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I have a detail page that gets a static item

```
 public static Article sharedArticle;
```

When i first load the page using

```
 SharedInformation.sharedArticle = (Article)lstOffline.SelectedItem;
Frame.Navigate(typeof(DetailsArticle));
```

However when i try to reload it from the previous Page after changing the value of `sharedArticle` I keep getting the same Page of `DetailsArticle` loaded with the old item.
How can I disallocate `DetailsArticle` after navigating to another page?

Comment: I think your problem might be related to Page's NavigationCacheMode. But, if you can provide little more code from your app, it makes pinpointing the problem easier.

Comment: I got the problem solved after reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18601048/windows-phone-8-page-lifecycle) , I was placing my code in the Contructor when I should do it in OnNavigatedTo .